# Button press on JQM/Phonegap app really touchy on Motorolla RAZR HD

Tags: jquery, cordova, phonegap-build, jquery-mobile

I'm developing a JQM/Phonegap app that we're in the process of testing right now.  I have a Motorola Axis 2 that I test the majority of my code on.  The customer that I am buildign this for has a Razr HD.

Where we are running into issues is the following.
I have a couple of JQM Listviews that act as buttons.  Basically when you click it, it will make an item as used via javascript function.  It will change the theme, icon and text on that `<li>` tag.

On my phone, other Android devices and iPhones, this process works as expected, however on his phone, he will click the button, then it immediately clicks again.

Has anyone experienced anything like this?  Do you have any ideas on what I can do to support the Razr?

Here's the code the flips the settings on the `<li>`

```
   // if a favorite is clicked, this will manage how it looks  
    $("#favorite_change").live("click", function(){
        var merchant_id = $(this).attr("merchant_id");
        var state = $(this).attr("state");
        // if it's a favorite, show that you can remove it 
        if (state=='1'){
            $('#favorites_text').html("Add Merchant to");
            $(this).attr("state",'0');
            $(this).closest("li").buttonMarkup({theme: 'c'});
            $(this).closest("li").removeClass("ui-btn-hover-e");
            setFavorite(merchant_id,'0');
        }else{
            // change it to allow them to add it again
            $('#favorites_text').html("Remove from");
            $(this).attr("state",'1');
            $(this).closest("li").buttonMarkup({theme: 'e'});
            $(this).closest("li").removeClass("ui-btn-hover-e");
            setFavorite(merchant_id,'1');
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  Changing

```
("#favorite_change").live("click", function(){
```

to

```
("#favorite_change").live("tap", function(){
```

Resolved it for the Razr and it works on the other phones I've tested on as well.